# Can I define an operator that has same parameter and return types?

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

I am trying the following:

```
public class DoubleNAND : ...
{
    public static implicit operator DoubleNAND(DoubleNAND d)
    {
        var n = new DoubleNAND();
        if (d.HasState)
            n.State = d.State;
        else if (d.HasValue2)
            n.Value = d.Value;
        return n;
    }
}
```

It fails with the message:

> Conversion operator with same parameter and return types.

Why?

I need to change the way a DoubleNAND gets asssigned to from another DoubleNAND.

Comment: Aren't you really wanting to write a copy constructor or clone method?

Comment: You unfortunately can't do copy constructors.

Comment: Can't you? Well [here's a Microsoft article explaining how to write a copy constructor in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that as it would change the meaning of the assignment, which is fundamental in C#. Consider:

```
DoubleNAND a = new ...
DoubleNAND b = new ...
a = b; // this means that now both a and b refer to the same object
```

If your code would work, these would be different objects. Even worse:

```
a = b;
var equal = object.ReferenceEquals(a, b); // equal == False !!!
equal = a.Equals(b); // equal == False!!! - depending on Equal implementation
```

This is also why it is not possible to override assignment operator in C#.

I believe you are trying to mimic C++ copy constructors, which is not possible in C#.

A convention in C# is to make this explicit, and it is usually done by introducing `Clone()` method.

Comment: I can understand this choice now

Answer (score 1):

1. Because it'd end up in an endless loop. (`DoubleNAND` -> `DoubleNAND` -> `DoubleNAND`...)
2. Even if that was fixed, we don't want operators that do something implicitly without saying.
3. **Because the spec says so.**

The proper way to do this is to use a constructor with an argument of its type, like this:

```
public DoubleNAND(DoubleNAND d) : this()
{
    if (d.HasState)
        State = d.State;
    else if (d.HasValue2)
        Value = d.Value;
}
```